# How can I control the placement of URL parameters in my route URL?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

Suppose I'm creating a website to display customer orders. I want to have pages showing:

1. A list of customers, which allows me to drill down to...
2. A list of orders for a given customer, which allows me to drill down to...
3. Details of a particular order for the customer.

If I create a few Razor pages, I might end up with the following structure:

`[Pages]
  Index.cshtml
  [Customer]
    Index.cshtml
    [Order]
      Index.cshtml`

The top-level page (list of customer) has no parameters, so the URL for that is just `/`.

The customer page (list of orders for a customer) needs a customer ID, so I can put `@page "{customerId}` at the top of the .cshtml file. It's URL will then be `/Customer/123`.

So far, so good. That URL makes sense.

Now for the order-detail page. This needs an order number, so let's put `@page "{orderNo}"` at the top of the .cshtml file. Its URL is... `/Customer/Order/54321`. Hmmm... I've lost the customer ID from the URL.

I can add the customer ID back in by making the `@page` directive include it (`@page "{customerId}/{orderNo}"`), but then the URL is `/Customer/Order/123/54321` - which doesn't look good.

How could I get the URL to look like `/Customer/123/Order/54321`?

Comment: "I've lost the customer ID from the URL." Do you need it? Surely you only need the order number? Or do you duplicate order numbers across customers?

Comment: @MikeBrind: Well, in reality it's not customers and orders at all, but let's say that the order number is a sequence number for each customer, so the order number on its own doesn't identify the customer. :-)

Comment: The route template for the Index page in your Orders folder will be `"/Customer/{customerid}/Order/{orderid}"`. Note the leading `/`. It overrides the path-based route: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing.

Comment: @MikeBrind: Ha! That works. It's not very DRY to have to repeat the path, and probably quite brittle in the face of changes to the structure of the site, but it works. Thanks! (Make this an answer so that I can accept it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [override route template](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes) to negate the path-based route that the framework generates. Override routes start with a leading `/`. In your example the solution is:

```
@page "/Customer/{customerid}/Order/{orderid}"
```

Note that this has the benefit of being robust in the face of changes to the structure of the site. You may, for example, decide in the future that nesting the *Order* folder within the *Customer* folder impedes discovery, but the override route will ensure that the page is found at the same URL regardless where you move the source files to within the *Pages* folder.